# How to write nginx rules/regexes to match empty non empty path

Tags: nginx

I want to have an nginx rule that will proxy requests with empty path `/` to a back end server, and another rule that match non empty paths, ex. `http://mysite/x/y/z`

The following two rules do not do this, the second one is catching all:

```
# empty path
location ^/?$ {
    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8000;
}

location / {
    expires -1;
    alias /var/static-site/;
}
```

I have tried `/.*/` for the second rule, without success...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the "=" modifier to process an exact match on "/":

```
location = / {
    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8000;
}

location / {
    expires -1;
    alias /var/static-site/;
}
```